# Azure emulator deployment dll location

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator, azure-emulator

From which folder does Azure emulator load the dlls for a web/worker role deployed to it? Does it use all the DLLs from the bin folder of my solution?

I am running into an issue with the emulator loading the wrong version of a dll and I am trying to debug it.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like the the emulator uses the DLLs from a folder called "csx" within the solution directory. This folder gets created on deploying to azure emulator and it is subfoldered by each role.

Comment: Side note: This folder does not get created or updated on normal builds. You have to invoke the "Publish" target on the ccproj (which is called "Package" in the Visual Studio context menu), or do an actual publish to azure or emulator.